# I absolutely cannot get my bot to send a embed message in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I absolutely cannot find a way to fix this, this is what I tried doing:

```
@client.command(aliases=['Info','information','Information'])
async def info(ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Info", description="This menu displays the info about this bot", color=#fff300())
      embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)       
      embed.add_field(name="placeholder", value="another placeholder", inline=False)
      embed.add_field(name="so much placeholder", value="Bit more placeholder", inline=False)
      embed.add_field(name="(placeholder text)", value="(placeholder text)", inline=True)
      embed.add_field(name="way too much placeholder", value="some more placeholder", inline=True)
      embed.add_field(name="more placeholder", value="placeholder", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have even used whatever websites I could, even the latest one and I couldn't find any way to fix the error, I keep getting a syntax error and I can't find anyway to fix it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is when initializing the embed

```py
embed = discord.Embed(..., color=#fff300())
```

Comments in python start with `#`, to fix it simply put it in quotes

```py
color="fff300"
```

Note: This will not work, you need to convert it to an int with base 16 (also it's `colour` not `color`):

```py
colour=int("fff300", 16)
# Or as `Nurqm` suggested
colour=0xfff300
```

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Info", description="This menu displays the info about this bot", colour=int("fff300", 16))
```

Comment: Or he can simply do `color=0xfff300`.

Comment: Yes, that's another way

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the syntax error always points to the "embed.add_field" lines, I can't see any way to fix that

Comment: There's no other syntax error, try the code

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Info", description="This menu displays the info about this bot", color=0xa3a3ff)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)       
  embed.add_field(name="placeholder", value="another placeholder", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="so much placeholder", value="Bit more placeholder", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="(placeholder text)", value="(placeholder text)", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="way too much placeholder", value="some more placeholder", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="more placeholder", value="placeholder", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

what I saw were a few indentations (spacing) errors and an error with the color format. Other than that, I see pretty much no errors and it should work, if not, please tell us what error you are exactly facing

[image]

Comment: I'd like to point out that you're using Better Discord which is against the Discord ToS. You're at risk of being banned from Discord.